# Bash weirdness when printing ${IFS@Q}

Tags: bash, shell

Isn't this supposed to work?  It looks like it should from the `info` page.

```
echo ${IFS@Q}
bash: ${IFS@Q}: bad substitution
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks.

EDIT: I took out my command prompt... it was an old BSD one that looked like stderr redirection.  My bad.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: In bash-4.4      '${PARAMETER@OPERATOR}'
         The expansion is either a transformation of the value of PARAMETER
         or information about PARAMETER itself, depending on the value of
         OPERATOR.  Each OPERATOR is a single letter:
    
         'Q'
              The expansion is a string that is the value of PARAMETER
              quoted in a format that can be reused as input.

Comment: What is the expected output / result?  First off, you can't redirect stderr to another process, but there are ways to pipe stderr to another process.  However, I can't see what "echo ${IFS@Q}" is supposed to accomplish with a pipe.  Lastly, I can't see what ${IFS@Q} is supposed to do.  Can you please explain what you want to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am an idiot.  I was reading `info` pages from one machine (version 4.4.0(2)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.7)) while bash-ing on another (version 4.2.46(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)).

It seems the `${@Q}` notation is new.

The output under bash-4.4 is:

```
echo ${IFS@Q}
$' \t\n'
```

Comment: Use `printf '%q\n' "$IFS"` for compatibility with older shells.

Comment: Oh, I like that `printf %q`.  Who knows what bash I'm going to hit?  I already found one machine without associative arrays (bash-3?), and had to re-write a bunch of code.